# Which of the following sentence about 'of noun' as an adj. is correct?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I have two objects A and B, A is of color green while B is of color blue. Are the following sentences correct?

> A and B are of different color.

and

> A and B are of different colors.

If not, how to correct it?

The above is a bad example, but my point is that when I have to use `of Noun` as an adjective and
A, B each has(or belongs to) a different one, would I have to append `s` to the `Noun`?

Comment: We usually just say *A is green* (where *of colour* is unnecessary and sounds rather stilted to me). By the same token, *A and B are different colours* - the preposition is entirely superfluous, and to me at least it's reminiscent of the peculiar "politically correct" requirement that it's somehow less "racist" to say ***person of colour*** rather than ***coloured person***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Sorry for my bad example... Actually the problem I'm facing is not colour but a technical noun in programming: "A is of a particular type, while B is of another type".

Comment: According to Google NGrams, the 10 most common words to follow ***are of different...*** are *types, sizes, kinds, lengths, ages, shapes, sorts, colours, forms, degrees* (interestingly, ***colors*** doesn't appear there, because overall totals are dominated be pre-1900 instances before the US spelling became widely established). But you'll note that ***all*** of them are plural forms.  That doesn't imply singular ***are of different type*** is "wrong", but it's certainly far less common. Most people don't include the preposition though - we just say ***A and B are different types***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for your clear explanation.